# Why undefined in doPost on Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to post data to Google Sheets automatically from my service.

But I get a strange error in my little script:

[image: 1]

I can't guess what's wrong

P.S. If I send empty JSON the script works OK (but there is no data)
P.P.S. My JSON:

[image: 2]

What I try to make:
Send data from CRM to Google Sheets

Comment: How are you sending the POST request? You seem to be clicking the "Debug" button to test, but the `e` variable in the `doPost()` function only gets data when you actually send the POST to the Web App URL. That's why you're getting it as undefined when testing in the editor. However, just looking at your code, it should append the data if you send the request to the endpoint.